# Variable substitution not working properly in Sphinx

Tags: python, versioning, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I have a documentation project made with [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/). I am using global variables by means of the configuration key `rst_epilog`. My `conf.py` file contains the following:

```
rst_epilog = """
.. |MY_VERSION| replace:: 2.1.0
"""
```

Then, in a rst page, I'm using the formerly defined variable (`VERSION`) as follows:

```
The version of my repo is: |MY_VERSION|

.. sourcecode:: bash

    git clone https://github.com/my-organization/my-repo.git
    cd my-repo
    git checkout |MY_VERSION|
```

After building the documentation, in the resulting HTML, the first variable is correctly substituted, but not the second:
[image]

Clearly the substitution does not work inside formatted source code blocks, which is very inconvenient.

Is it possible to workaround this issue?

PS: I also tried with `rst_prolog` with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make the substitution work:

```
.. parsed-literal::

   git clone https://github.com/my-organization/my-repo.git
   cd my-repo
   git checkout |MY_VERSION|
```

With the [`parsed-literal`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal-block) directive, you can have substitutions (and other inline markup) but there is no syntax highlighting.

With [`code-block`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html) (or`sourcecode`, or `highlight`), you can have syntax highlighting but inline markup is not processed.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Sphinx extension which provides `substitution-code-block` for this purpose.

It allows you to define `substitutions` in `conf.py` and then use these substitutions in `.. substitution-code-block` blocks.

This extension is at https://github.com/adamtheturtle/sphinx-substitution-extensions.

However, this is a very small amount of code.
To enable this in your own codebase without a third party extension, create a module in your codebase with the following contents:

```
"""
Custom Sphinx extensions.
"""

from typing import List

from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.directives.code import CodeBlock


class SubstitutionCodeBlock(CodeBlock):  # type: ignore
    """
    Similar to CodeBlock but replaces placeholders with variables.
    """

    def run(self) -> List:
        """
        Replace placeholders with given variables.
        """
        app = self.state.document.settings.env.app
        new_content = []
        self.content = self.content  # type: List[str]
        existing_content = self.content
        for item in existing_content:
            for pair in app.config.substitutions:
                original, replacement = pair
                item = item.replace(original, replacement)
            new_content.append(item)

        self.content = new_content
        return list(CodeBlock.run(self))


def setup(app: Sphinx) -> None:
    """
    Add the custom directives to Sphinx.
    """
    app.add_config_value('substitutions', [], 'html')
    app.add_directive('substitution-code-block', SubstitutionCodeBlock)
```

Then, use this module the `extensions` defined in `conf.py`.
Then, set the `substitutions` variable in `conf.py` e.g. to `[('|foo|', 'bar')]` to replace `|foo|` with `bar` in every `substitution-code-block`.